# Memory leak writing string to file AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, file-io, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Using the windows process explorer I can see that memory in my program goes up, then gets collected and drops back down in a constant loop until I uncomment the following function:

```
protected function marker( output:FileStream, file:File, i:int, j:int ):void
{
    output.open( file, FileMode.APPEND );
    output.writeUTFBytes( i + "\t" + j + "\n" );    
    output.close();             
}
```

With this function being called, the memory increases unboundedly until it reaches around 2GB and the whole thing crashes with an out of memory error. I was hoping someone could shed some light on where the leak here is and how to fix it, since I would like to be able to call this function reasonably frequently. Thanks. I think it's creating a new String each time but don't know why it's not being collected if this is in fact what's happening.

Comment: Use **Adobe Scout** to learn what kind of instances multiply and don't go away. Although, I doubt the **String**s are to blame.

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop so I don't think I can use Scout.

Comment: How is that relevant? You should turn **advanced telemetry** on in Projects Settings > Compiler Options, build your app, then you can profile it with Scout as much as you like.

Comment: The other thing you might want to try is to open the **FileStream** just once instead doing it over and over (which is what, I guess, you do). If you don't exit your script to switch frames, GC doesn't get a chance to collect anything, which leads to out-of-memory crash.